# Using a while loop and continuing to execute the lines below C# Console

Tags: c#

Someone can help me?
I have a little doubt how I can load a `while(true))` in the c# console and continue loading the code from the lines below (continuing to perform the loop). (I know the loop is infinite but does anyone know or can help me with a solution?)

I want the console to be constantly changing the title to something "Random" so I use the loop.

```
while(true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] numbs = new int[100];
    string[] palavras = { "hi", "2", "bye", "ok", "nah", "idk", "done", "local", "can you", "bruh", "example", "nope", "hehe" };
    int index = rnd.Next(palavras.Length);
    Console.Title = (palavras[index]);             
}
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Why would you want a loop to run indefinitely? This sounds like a prime example of the XY question. I wouldn't be surprised if you're looking for something like a Cronjob in reality.

Comment: have you tried ```watch 'mono myprogram.exe'```? try using git bash or cygwin in if you're using windows

Comment: What is preventing you from executing the code? I'm not following.

Comment: I think what the OP wants is for this loop to _run as a coroutine_, separately from the main program logic - so as long as the user (or program) isn't doing anything else then terminal/console window's `Title` is updated like an animation.

Comment: Yes Dai, that's right

Comment: @Bife Then simply wrap your code in a coroutine then (in C# coroutines are represented by `async` methods) and invoke it from your `Main` method and ensure other methods are non-blocking (i.e. **do not use** `Thread.Sleep` or any of the `Console.Read...` methods).

Comment: Ah, so you mean the code below the loop code you've shown above, as opposed to "the code below" (as in... "the code in my question")?

Comment: Your code is incorrect btw, the `Random` object needs to be initialized once _outside and before_ the loop body - not reinitialized in every iteration inside the loop body.

Comment: @Dai It is working correctly, it chooses a random word from the ones I flagged in the code

Comment: But I see what you mean

Comment: @Bife No, it isn't "working correctly", it just seems like it's working correctly the same way that a stopped-clock is still correct twice a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string[] palavras = { "hi", "2", "bye", "ok", "nah", "idk", "done", "local", "can you", "bruh", "example", "nope", "hehe" };
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0))
        .Select(x => palavras[rnd.Next(palavras.Length)])
        .Subscribe(x => Console.Title = x);
        
Console.WriteLine("This code continue to run while the title updates.");
```

When you want the titles to stop updating, just call `subscription.Dispose()`.